# Alternative C++ Compilers?

Tags: c++

I want to start learning C++, so I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express, and the entire application freezes and crashes every time I try to compile (debug and release build) something (I have tried running it in Admin Mode). Is there a good alternative compiler that I could still use VS 2010 as the IDE?

Comment: I wouldn't just brush this off. Compilers don't just crash for no reason, even MS compilers aren't written by amateurs. There's either a problem with your specific system/install, or you've triggered a bug that should be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)

Comment: What version of MS Windows are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why it crashes for you. But there are lots of C++ compilers out there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.2FC.2B.2B_compilers

And there is a thread below to use GCC with Visual Studio

[GCC with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216025/gcc-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

if its crashing, I would think its more likely the ide is crashing, not the compiler.

you can use the compiler from the command line as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Well I noticed that it is not the compiler (I don't think, I did not run the command line version), but when VS tries to run the compiled executable. When I go to the project folder and run the executable myself it runs fine. So I guess I will just have to deal with this bug.

Answer (score 1):

How about bloodshed dev-cpp. It supports cygwin and mingw.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***NO!*** There is no other compiler that plugs into VS2010 or VS anything else. Each version of VS is tightly tied to its corresponding version of the Microsoft compiler.

As an alternative, how about:

1. VirtualBox
2. Linux
3. g++, perhaps enhanced with Eclipse / C++ for an IDE.

Cost: $0.

Comment: I'd add that, as of 2021, this answer is no longer correct, (and if this MS blog is to be believed, it was no longer true in 2017: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/). Well, it's still correct for VS2010, but not for more recent versions of Visual Studio.

It is now apparently possible to use either GCC or Clang with Visual Studio (though I admittedly didn't try either).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse for C++

Answer (score 0):

If you want something with IDE, I would suggest g++, Eclipse and CDT plugins. Works quite well.

You can use g++ on command line if you are comfortable that way.