# How to best use GCC with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I know this thread
[GCC with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216025/gcc-with-visual-studio)
but to me it seems that everything mentioned there is rather outdated and it seems to be the tenor is: don't do it

Who knows a better step by step explanation 
thank you in advance
Oops

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC with Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216025/gcc-with-visual-studio)

Comment: @Andrew: well yeah, he linked to it in his question!

Comment: @Inverse: That comment was posted automatically when I voted to close the question.  I'd not realised it'd do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unfortunately there is still no ***plugin*** for *Visual Studio*. Using makefiles seems to still be the best idea and there are several tools to automate their building.

As far as I remember, the best tool for this that I've used is [Makefile Wizard,](http://www.icd.no/download/Tools/MakefileWizard/MakefileWizard%20v1_1.rar) which allows almost automatic *VC project to makefile* converting. Also to mention, it can be paired with some external building system.