# Using different compiler in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

This maybe a beginner question but could not find proper answer on the internet.
I am curious can I use *some other* compiler (which I like) in Visual Studio 10?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a Makefile project with VC instead of an MSBuild project, that way you can specify the exact compiler in your makefile.

Comment: read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452.aspx

Comment: You can take a look to the answers of this question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216025/gcc-with-visual-studio

Comment: Kinda pointless to spend that kind of money on a text editor.

Comment: @Dai: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Hans: he may already have VS. Also, the free Express version's editor is still pretty nice (though it can't be enhanced with add-ons).

Comment: @pseudonym_127: The menu item "File/New/Project.../Makefile Project" lets you have a project with all the files in it for editing and code navigation. You get to specify commands to build the project (the commands can use `make` with a makefile or any other build tool you want). The minor drawback is that VS doesn't maintain the build files - you do. The major drawback is that you don't get to use the VS debugger. I sometimes do this with an embedded toolchain, where VS editing and navigation are much better than the embedded toolchain's IDE - I just have to switch to the other IDE to debug.

Comment: @Michael Blurr: from what I have heard/understood so far it is possible to achieve above with VS + Makefiles right?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 I deleted the unrelated parts of your question, I hope it's not a problem. Asking several questions in a single post should be avoided. If you want to, you can still post them as separate questions, though.

Comment: I would be inclined to rewind a bit and ask the question "What are you really trying to achieve?".  The effort of trying to get a different compiler integrated into VS is unlikley to be worth the hassle unless there's a *really* compelling reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

As of Visual Studio 2010, it is conceptually possible to integrate another compiler. In the book ‘*Inside the Microsoft Build Engine, Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Buid*’ 2nd edition, on page 338, the chapter ‘*Adding a New Platform and Platform Toolset*’ the process of adding gcc to visual studio is explained.

However, while it is possible, it has always remained as a concept. To my awareness, nobody has actually been up to the task and publicly disclosed the results. But even with this support, you'd still be lacking debugging facilities.  Which would require your compiler of choice to generate *.pdb* files and/or extend visual studio with a new *local debugger*

In summary it's quite a venture

Answer (score 0):

You can use other compiler [Intel c++](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers) in VS. I don't think any other compiler supports VS.The main reason behind it is lack of plug-ins in VS. But you can use cmake scripts to compile your code in different compilers. With eclipse you can use most of the compilers (VS,gcc). Code blocks also allows you to choose the compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use Intel C++,and even MATLAB 7.1 or later for sure..here is a reference to use MATLAB[It gives a step by step procedure to use MATLAB with VS](http://www.mathworks.in/support/solutions/en/data/1-F9VB0V/index.html)

You can also write Java programs and include javac compiler for it...you can refer this if needed..[Including javac with VS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/29bad65d-5674-46ca-95f4-1406b9b37639)

I kno this is surely possible from VS 2010 but not sure for the b4 editions..hope it helps..