# how to specify compiler and compiler option if build uses nmake (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution which uses nmake, so I cannot specify from property pages which compiler options I want to use, nor can I specify the compiler to be used.
I want be able to use intel compiler with visual studio, and I simply need to know where to make does changes.

Thank you.

Comment: Related to this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538856/using-different-compiler-in-visual-studio. Probably you need to change your Makefile explicitly to say you want to use the intel compiler.

Comment: Don't you have a makefile?

Comment: @Tushar and zdan where should I look for this makefile? And how to actually know which makefile is used?

Comment: If you are using nmake, go to project properties -> Configuration Properties -> NMake and look at "Build Command line". If it contains make, the folder which contains your vcxproj contains Makefile.

Comment: @Tushar the build command line reads: C:\ue4\intel\UnrealEngine-4.0.2-release\UnrealEngine-4.0.2-release\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat MyProject11Editor Win64 Debug "$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName).uproject" I cannot see make anywhere there, can you?

Comment: Well that Build.bat file must either use a makefile, project file or invoke the compiler/linker directly. You'll have to dig in there to figure it out.

Comment: @zdan how it would invoke compiler directly?