# Compile Linux project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have a project in Linux, but it's cross platform code. How can I compile it in Visual Studio 2008 for the Windows part?

Comment: Create a solution, add the source files, and try to compile. Fix the errors one by one.

Comment: One way to fix some problems would be to try Visual Studio 2015. It's about 7 years newer. *A lot* has happened in that time.

Comment: You could install Cygwin and the latest gcc on your windows system and compile it using the makefile.

Comment: To add one more solution: if the code is too specific for a Microsoft Compiler you might want to use mingw: http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1)Use the windows version of same compiler(Hopefully GCC) + compiler extension for Visual studio.

2)Start creating Visual Studio project and fix compilation/linking errors occurred due to change in compiler/language standard supported by them.

Both the approaches doesn't guarantee your code will work directly, you may have to replace/#ifdef certain parts of code not supported by the platform.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216025/gcc-with-visual-studio