# Which IDE Should I use for C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, ide, ssh

Which IDE for C++ should I use on Windows?

Is there an IDE with support for editing over SSH on a GNU/Linux server?

I have very big C++ project without docs and editing it with text editor very difficult =(

Comment: So do you want an IDE for Windows, or for Linux?  Your first two questions are confusing.  Is this Windows code or not?

Comment: Duplicate (thanks Xorlev): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows

Comment: That link is with regard to editing and running on windows. This is not a duplicate if he is editing on windows and running on a Linux server. But he really should clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows I prefer:

[Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com) + [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:de)

Answer (score 14):

On Windows, it's hard to beat the freely available [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP).

A viable alternative would be the [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads), which is lightweight and comes with the completely awesome Qt library.

Comment: +1 for 'completely awesome' ;)

Comment: Qt is only overrated if you've never had to work with another UI toolkit. ;)

Answer (score 7):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is very powerful editor for both C++ and many other languages.  It sounds like you're looking to develop from a Windows system for Linux?

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) will make it possible for you edit files via SSH.

If your project is being stored in CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, et al--Eclipse has plugins to integrate with these as well...

Comment: My standard eclipse Galileo distribution has support for remote systems, including remote shells / ssh terminials etc.

Comment: Unless you create s/w with a GUI, then I have to agree. Eclipse is a great editor, use dat many companies, with great features and lots of plugins (btw, there isn't a package for kosmic, if you are using Ubuntu)

Comment: See also CodeBlocks  http://www.codeblocks.org/  NetBeans http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/  et al   and don't forget The Free Country http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Netbeans 6.8](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html), specifically the Remote Development section:

> Use the Development Host Manager in the C/C++ Options windows to define remote hosts. You can then use development tools on those hosts to build and run projects from your client system. Benefit from faster synchronization with the remote host.

I have been very happy using Netbeans remote debugging for a PHP project. Just configure it and on run it will to automatically ssh files to the remote server.

Alternatively, Visual Studio offers arguably the best C++ editor for windows C++ development, and you can script it to upload the files to a linux server.

Finally, you may want to look into Eclipse CDT as well.

Answer (score 1):

devc++ seems interesting. It's free and makes use of MinGW as a POSIX layer. It's great if you're interested in doing cross-platform development on Windows and Linux/UNIX.

Comment: Bug ridden and no longer being developed. If you use it, you should immediately switch to Code::Blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! (It's been a long while since I've had to develop C++ on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

If your Linux box has x libraries you can run eclipse cdt on it and use a cygwin x server to display it on Windows. I have been using this setup since the usb ports stopped working on my Solaris box.  The results are very good. Eclipse runs on my Solaris box but behaves like a Windows app on my windows box, the code builds and runs on Solaris, copy and paste works most of the time too.

Run x server on windows. Use putty to ssh to your Linux box with x forwarding. Start eclipse and it displays on windows. Use nohup to keep eclipse alive if you close putty.

Answer (score 1):

[CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org).

It comes with MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

For editing you can use basically any editor that has FTP/SFTP support (I've used [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org): free, a great tool with loads of plugins; played with [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/): really cool but pretty expensive) or map the target drive in Windows using [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) or anything else of that nature.
Then use Putty's [plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) for compiling/building.

Answer (score 0):

For ssh-support, I'd say putty and emacs-on-server is an option. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a programming project stored on a linux server, I prefer Git. I do not know if more people are involved, but using git can make programming in a group a lot easier.

And as IDE I prefer Visual Studio. The RC for 2010 is now available at MSDN. 
[Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/default.mspx). Maybe you should give it a try.