# C compiler/IDE for Windows 7?

Tags: c, windows, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)

What is a good compiler and/or IDE for C that runs on modern Windows systems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows

Answer (score 9):

If you are building pure Windows apps nothing beats [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us). There is a [free](http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/) Version as well. There is also [Bloodshed Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/index.html) that can compile C, but it isn't nearly as well documented or a feature rich as any of the versions Visual Studio, but it is useful in building things that originated on POSIX/*NIX systems, because it uses the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) compiler. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) also has a plug-in for C and C++, but again it isn't as well documented as Visual Studio. [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html) has C and C++ support as well. The caveat with Eclipse and Netbeans is they run on the JVM and will need lots of RAM to perform well, but with "modern" Windows systems this should not be an issue.

Comment: Dunno about needing lots of RAM these days. I have Eclipse open with big projects and it's only using 51MB, although that probably doesn't include the JVM.

Comment: Well everything really needs "lots" of RAM these days :-)

Comment: I wanna create C apps that will be multi-platform, is VS still the best candidate in that case?

Comment: @Shimmy I do it all the time, as long as you stick to ANSI C you will be good.

Comment: @Jarrod is there a way to enforce ANSI-C in Vs?

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us)

Or its free version [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is the obvious answer, but also consider :

[QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) - especially if you are doing Qt

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) - if you want the same IDE for other languages.