# Eclipse CDT vs NetBeans C++ vs 

Tags: c++, ide, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)

Hello, everyone.

For a long time now, for C/C++ development, I have been using Notepad++ and the command line for compiling C/C++ programs. Now, I want to start using an IDE, and I have tried out quite a few. Currently, I am thinking of either Eclipse CDT or Netbeans C++, but other suggestions are welcome too. The problem is that I cannot find any recent, unbiased comparisons of both of these softwares. So, I would like to hear opinions on which IDE is better. By "better", I mean in terms of code-completion, configurability, ease of use, speed, and especially debugging capabilities and debugging speed. I really need help on choosing a C/C++ IDE. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Because I develop on both Windows and Linux, I need an IDE that is compatible with both Windows and Linux, and by default uses GCC by default, so Visual Studio is not an option for me. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows) (And poll questions should be CW)

Comment: @Billy I forgot in my post to mention that because I develop on both Windows and Linux, I need an IDE that is compatible with both Windows and Linux, and by default uses the MinGW/GCC compiler toolset, which means I cannot use Visual Studio, so my post is not a duplicate of the thread you mentined above.

Comment: @user: Okay, there are [plenty of other questions in that vein as well](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+platform+IDE+C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Eclipse for years, and it is a solid IDE with a wide range of capabilities.  If you haven't tried it out to see how well it fits your needs, I would recommend giving it a shot.

That being said, I have recently started using NetBeans and I must say that I like it a bit better than Eclipse.  It seems to be more streamlined than Eclipse (less memory usage, faster to start up, etc).  I have not tested its built-in debugging capabilities however, so I can't say anything on that front.

Thankfully, there are a number of freely-available, quality IDEs out there.  I would recommend installing a handful and trying to perform the same basic set of tasks in each (create a new project, add in your source code, build, run, debug, etc) and see how they feel.  Pretty quickly, you should start to get a feeling about which ones meet your needs and which are lacking.

Answer (score 1):

After your question edit:

I'd strongly recommend Code::Blocks: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to throw in my vote for Visual Studio.

Comment: That's not really going to work very well on Linux, though.

Comment: @Timo: The original question didn't say anything about Linux.

Comment: Fair enough - by the time I saw the question it did mention Linux. Actually, I'd probably recommend Visual Studio as a decent Windows C++ IDE, too.

Comment: You can use VS on Windows pointing at a Linux box with VisualGDB.