# IDE for C Programming?

Tags: c, windows-7, ide

Can any one suggest me a Best IDE for C programming ( With auto completion feature)?

Comment: Try a few. Use the one you like the best. VS2010 has "intellisense".

Comment: which OS? linux/windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)

Comment: Checkout the duplicate question: Short summary - there's no best IDE, tastes are different. Try the major IDEs yourself (VS2010, Eclipse, Code::Blocks, Netbeans, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use vim with plugins like snipMate, c-support etc.

Comment: Does it have"intellisense" feature???

Comment: "intellisense" is Microsoft's autocompletion

Comment: you can use CTRL-n to autocomplete already entered words(either in the same file or from some preloaded dictionary), but I don't know of a way in which you can do API auto-completion e.g. like Eclipse or Visual Studio do. But I'm sure there should be some plugin for that, just that I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

I like Xcode on OS X.

It has auto complete.