# expected declaration specifier error

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am in intro programming and struggling with this assignment any help is appreciated! Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

int cardNum(int firstCard, int secondCard; 
int highLow;
int score;

score = 0;   
srand(time(NULL));

printf("The current card is a %d\n" ,firstCard(2,14));
printf("\n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
scanf("%d" ,highLow);

if (cardNum > 1 && cardNum < 11)
{        
     printf ("The card is: %d ,secondCard.");
}        
else if (cardNum == 11)
{
    printf ("The card is: Jack"); 
}       
else if (cardNum == 12)
{
    printf ("The card is: Queen"); 
}       
else if (cardNum == 13)
{
    printf ("The card is: King"); 
}       
else if cardNum == 14)
{
    printf ("The card is: Ace"); 
}       
{
if (highLow == 1 && secondCard > firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard < firstCard)
    {   
        score = score + 1; 
        printf ("\n You have guessed correctly.");
        printf ("\n Your current score is %d ,score!\n");
        printf("The current card is a ("%d" ,cardOne). \n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    }    
else if (highLow == 1, && secondCard < firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard > firstCard)  
    {
        score = score - 1;
        printf ("The card is: %d ,secondCard.");
        printf ("\n You have guessed incorrectly.");
        printf ("\n Your current score is %d ,score!\n");
        printf ("The current card is a %d ,cardOne."); 
        printf ("\n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    }
else if (secondCard == firstCard)
    {
        printf ("\n Matching cards, no change in score");
    }
else if (highLow == 0)
    {
        printf ("\n Thanks for playing! Your final score is %d, score.");
    }
else
    {
        printf ("\n Incorrect input. Please enter 0, 1 or 2");      
    }
}    
return(0);
}
```

These are the errors:

```
a3.c: In function ‘main’:
a3.c:24:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘score’
a3.c:25:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘srand’
a3.c:27:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘printf’
a3.c:28:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘printf’
a3.c:29:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘scanf’
a3.c:31:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘if’
a3.c:52:9: error: ‘highLow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
a3.c:52:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
a3.c:52:25: error: ‘secondCard’ undeclared (first use in this function)
a3.c:52:38: error: ‘firstCard’ undeclared (first use in this function)
a3.c:52:49: error: expected expression before ‘||’ token
```

I know about the undeclared part because I was supposed to make random numbers and store them but I still havent quite figure that out (any advice would be awesome) but mainly I am concerned about the extensive list of expected declaration specifiers.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at this line: `int cardNum(int firstCard, int secondCard; `

Comment: and this line: `if (highLow == 1 && secondCard > firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard < firstCard)`

Comment: and this line: `else if (highLow == 1, && secondCard < firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard > firstCard)`

Answer (score 3):

1)`int cardNum(int firstCard, int secondCard;`

Instead of this you should write

`int cardNum, int firstCard, int secondCard;`

because you are declaring variables

2)`if (highLow == 1 && secondCard > firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard < firstCard)`

instead of this write statement given below

`if (highLow == 1 && secondCard > firstCard) || (highLow == 2 && secondCard < firstCard)`

3)`else if (highLow == 1, && secondCard < firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard > firstCard)`

you should write

`else if (highLow == 1 && secondCard < firstCard) || (highLow == 2 && secondCard > firstCard)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

int cardNum, int firstCard, int secondCard; 
int highLow;
int score;

score = 0;   
srand(time(NULL));

printf("The current card is a %d\n", firstCard(2,14));
printf("\n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
scanf("%d" ,highLow);

if (cardNum > 1 && cardNum < 11)
{        
     printf ("The card is: %d ,secondCard.");
}        
else if (cardNum == 11)
{
    printf ("The card is: Jack"); 
}       
else if (cardNum == 12)
{
    printf ("The card is: Queen"); 
}       
else if (cardNum == 13)
{
    printf ("The card is: King"); 
}       
else if cardNum == 14)
{
    printf ("The card is: Ace"); 
}       
{
if ((highLow == 1 && secondCard > firstCard) || (highLow == 2 && secondCard < firstCard))
    {   
        score = score + 1; 
        printf ("\n You have guessed correctly.");
        printf ("\n Your current score is %d ,score!\n");
        printf("The current card is a ("%d" ,cardOne). \n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    }    
else if ((highLow == 1 && secondCard < firstCard) || (highLow == 2 && secondCard > firstCard))  
    {
        score = score - 1;
        printf ("The card is: %d ,secondCard.");
        printf ("\n You have guessed incorrectly.");
        printf ("\n Your current score is %d ,score!\n");
        printf ("The current card is a %d ,cardOne."); 
        printf ("\n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    }
else if (secondCard == firstCard)
    {
        printf ("\n Matching cards, no change in score");
    }
else if (highLow == 0)
    {
        printf ("\n Thanks for playing! Your final score is %d, score.");
    }
else
    {
        printf ("\n Incorrect input. Please enter 0, 1 or 2");      
    }
}    
return(0);
}
```

Comment: at least u should say what u ve changed :(

Answer (score -1):

Look at this line:

```
int cardNum(int firstCard, int secondCard;
```

I guess it should be:

```
int cardNum, int firstCard, int secondCard;
```

---

Also the if statements are wrong. I guess it should be:

```
if ((highLow == 1 && secondCard > firstCard) || (highLow == 2, && secondCard < firstCard))
```

and

```
else if ((highLow == 1 && secondCard < firstCard) || (highLow == 2 && secondCard > firstCard))
```

---

You should start learning C from scratch.

Answer (score -3):

Just use any [Integrated development environment (IDE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) with syntactic errors highlighting. We do not want to be your editors.

Here is some useful links (obviously any C++ IDE will check C syntax too):

- [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)
- [C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)
- [Which IDE is best for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93326/which-ide-is-best-for-c)

Happy coding!