# C++ insert element inside list of struct

Tags: c++

The following code has an error as noted, please help in this regards.

```
typedef enum L3 {e_s, e_off,e_on};
struct L
{
    L3 List3;
    float value;
    int MT_ID;
};

list <L> eventlist1;

L rr={e_s,1.3,3};

eventlist1.push_back.(rr);   // here is the error
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to include error message to your post (so we don't need to guess) and ask exact question (with question mark at the end).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo: `eventlist1.push_back.(rr)` (you need to remove the dot between `back` and `(rr)`
Correct it to `eventlist1.push_back(rr);`

Answer (score 0):

You have syntactic error in your code. Use [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), to check for syntax errors even before compilation.

- [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)
- [C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

eventlist1.push_back.(rr); ==> shouldn't this be eventlist1.push_back(rr);

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum L3 {e_s, e_off,e_on};
struct L
{
    L3 List3;
    float value;
    int MT_ID;
};

list <L> eventlist1;

L rr={e_s,1.3,3};

eventlist1.push_back(rr);   // push_back(VALUE)
```

Reference C++98/C++11 : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/