# I'm getting "undefined reference" errors for a bunch of my functions and I can't figure out why

Tags: c++

Every single function in my class is giving me this error. I'll throw in my 3 parameter constructor as an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mixed{
    public:
        Mixed(int i, int n, int d);    
    private:
        int integer, numerator, denominator;
};
```

and my cpp:

```
#include "mixed.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

Mixed::Mixed(int i, int n, int d){
    int valid;
    int negatives = 0;

    if (d == 0){
        valid = 0;
    }
    if (d < 0 | n < 0 | i < 0 && valid != 0){ //if there are any negatives and it hasn't been made invalid
        if (i < 0){ //start counting negatives
            negatives++;
        }
        if (n < 0){
            negatives++;
        }
        if (d < 0){
            negatives++;
        }
        if (negatives > 1){ //invalid if more than one negative value
            valid = 0;
        }
        else {
            valid = 1;
        }

        if (i != 0 && valid != 0){ //check for order if it hasn't already been made invalid
            if (n < 0 | d < 0){ //invalid if integer is non zero, but one of the others is negative
                valid = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (n != 0 && d < 0){ //invalid if integer is zero, numerator is nonzero, and denominator is negative
            valid = 0;
        }
        else if (valid != 0){ //if it hasn't already been invalidated, it's valid
            valid = 1;
        }
    }

    if (valid == 0){
        this -> integer = 0;
        this -> numerator = 0;
        this -> denominator = 0;
    }
    else{
        this -> integer = i;
        this -> numerator = n;
        this -> denominator = d;
    }
}
```

the main.cpp where my class is being used does contain

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mixed.h"
using namespace std;
```

My errors look like:

/tmp/ccbdj59O.o: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to`Mixed::Mixed(int, int, int)'

I'm at my wit's end and it feels like it's an obvious mistake. Thoughts?

Comment: You didn't tell us how you're trying to link everything together. Chances are you forgot to include the `cpp` file containing the definitions for `Mixed`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I'm just hitting build in Sublime.

Comment: Open a terminal and try building your program. Once you know how to do that, use Sublime or whatever IDE to automate the task.

Comment: You should use `||` for logical-OR, not `|`

Answer (score 1):

You want to compile **both** cpp files and link them together.

This can be done using g++ with the command

```
g++ mixed.cpp main.cpp -o output_file
```

This compiles both files and links them together. You can also do that separately:

```
g++ -c mixed.cpp -o mixed.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ main.o mixed.o -o output_file
```

If you don't know how to use the command line look [this](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0010.php) tutorial if you are working on Linux (I guess you are, based on the fact that you got a linker error and thus have g++ working). On Windows you will probably want to use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows) for suggestions.

Looking at your comment you are using Sublime Text to build your files, maybe try opening your working folder (File > Open Folder...) instead of a single file. Anyway I think it's better to know what is happening behind scenes.